# skype 4.3 cannot connect to account on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, skype

I have being using Skype for a long time on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
From this morning on, Skype simple cannot connect to my account anymore.

That is my Skype version:

> Skype 4.3.0.37
>   © 2014 Skype and/or Microsoft

My Ubuntu system:

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-3.0-amd64:cxx-3.0-noarch:cxx-3.1-amd64:cxx-3.1-noarch:cxx-3.2-amd64:cxx-3.2-noarch:cxx-4.0-amd64:cxx-4.0-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-3.1-amd64:desktop-3.1-noarch:desktop-3.2-amd64:desktop-3.2-noarch:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.0-amd64:graphics-3.0-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.1-amd64:graphics-4.1-noarch:languages-3.2-amd64:languages-3.2-noarch:languages-4.0-amd64:languages-4.0-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:multimedia-3.2-amd64:multimedia-3.2-noarch:multimedia-4.0-amd64:multimedia-4.0-noarch:multimedia-4.1-amd64:multimedia-4.1-noarch:printing-3.2-amd64:printing-3.2-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch:qt4-3.1-amd64:qt4-3.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Any suggestion why or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Skype is down today. Nothing to do with Ubuntu. Please refer [here](http://heartbeat.skype.com/)

Comment: As this was only temporary voted "Problem went away all by it's own"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skype has some issues today, wait some time and check later again.

http://heartbeat.skype.com/2015/09/skype_presence_issues.html

In the meantime you can use **skype web service** as a workaround.

Open **web.skype.com** in your browser and log in to skype service.

**Updated information from Skype :**

"We have identified the network issue which prevented users from logging in and using Skype today. We're in the process of reconnecting our users, and focused on restoring full service."

**Recommendation to ubuntu users :**

As this problem is close to being off-topic : first check  http://heartbeat.skype.com/  in the future !

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that! I will wait and see what happens! I will give a feedback when the issue is solved.

Comment: I was going to check the answer as correct but it was before the 9 min required. Now it is done! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Skype online is working fine! Thank you so much for the fast reply!